# Image doesn't load in Picasso

Tags: android, image, uri, picasso

I have tried a lot of things to resolve my problem found on the forum but I was actually unable to open an image using Picasso library.

Here is my part of code concerned, thanks someone who can give me a solution.

```
File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+item_list.get(i).getItem_url()+".png");
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(filepath);

    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(item_list.get(i).getItem_name());
    Picasso.with(context).load(fileUri).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
```

and the graddle dependences :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Plz, just provide the gradle dependency that you used for Picasso in your build.gradle file

Comment: any error message appear on logcat ?

Comment: I haven't any error on log

Comment: The path you are getting from the external storage is correct?

Comment: Yes, i had print it to verify and i think it is correct, here is the value : "/storage/emulated/0/Screenshot_20170624.png"

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolve my problem by adding "file://" before the path. And by settings authorization of the app on the settings of my phone. I will make in the futur a popup at the launch to select authorization on my app.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getAbsolutePath()` for accessing file in External storage

change your code to:

```
File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator +item_list.get(i).getItem_url()+".png");
```

Also make sure you request [Runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for Sdk>=23

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT**

For Internal Storage Use:

```
File filePath = getFileStreamPath(item_list.get(i).getItem_url()+".png");
Picasso.with(context).load(filePath).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Yes, true i had forgotten to provide permission for writing. I added getAbsolutePath and the permission but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: make sure your `item_list.get(i).getItem_url()+".png"`...resides in your sd card

Comment: Actually it is on the internal memory of the phone. How do i access to the internal storage ?